# Dynamic Categorization Based on Averages

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to categorize students based on score averages in Power BI but have run into lots of issues. I would like be able to categorize the averages into buckets depending on what filters are applied to the date. For example, if I filter on two months I would like the results to be bucketed based on the average of the two months.

Here is a sample of the data I will be using:

```
Date    Score   Student Category
Jan-20  0.8     Jim     Above 80
Feb-20  0.75    Jim     Below 80
Mar-20  0.7     Jim     Below 80
Jan-20  0.9     Andrea  Above 80
Feb-20  0.95    Andrea  Above 80
Mar-20  0.92    Andrea  Above 80
Jan-20  0.6     Max     Below 80
Feb-20  0.65    Max     Below 80
Mar-20  0.7     Max     Below 80
```

I would like to be able to show how many students fall into the above 80 and below 80 scorecards depending on what filter i choose. For example, if i filtered on jan and feb, it would show 2 students below 80 and 1 student above 80. If I only filtered on Jan, it would show 2 students above 80 and 1 below 80.

I have tried to create a measure to calculate the average score per student, then fed that into a switch statement to represent the categories, but this doesn't seem to work with the filters. Any suggestions for a better way to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You alredy have the Category column or that column is what you are looking for?

Comment: I can make that on a month by month basis, but i would like one that interacts with the filter so that it is dynamic.

Comment: I managed to make it work with a summarized table, i'll comment that as the answer if nobody else has a better solution.